# A mistaken type of rddle

Tags: riddle, wordplay

Guess the word:

> To all I’m known as a negative flaw.
>   Negative, I’m beneficial to all.

Hint:

> the title

Comment: I really like this riddle

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The answer is

> a **TYPO**.

To all I’m known as a negative flaw.

> It's a mistake, yes.

Negative, I’m beneficial to all.

> Type O-negative blood is (was?) considered the "universal donor" type, so can be of benefit to everyone.

<sub>Full disclosure:

at the time I solved this, the hint pointed pretty clearly in the right direction. I may not have solved it without the hint.</sub>

Comment: EURGH I thought of that but I literally was like nahhh it can't be >:( EURGHHHH lol gj tho

Comment: I sure hope *that* will never need to be a benefit to anyone...

Answer (score 7):

To all I’m known as a negative flaw.

> Rddle has no I - eye - so blind. Being blind is a flaw.

"A simple little rddle"

Negative, I’m beneficial to all.

> Going backwards, there are 2 I's - eyes - which are beneficial to all, at least those who benefit from 2 eyes.

Comment: The first part makes sense, I think the last part is a bit of a stretch. Perhaps the negative of "blind" would be "vision", and the beneficial to all could be referring to someone with vision (a visionary).

Comment: @Jonathan that makes sense too. I was playing the word play angle.

Comment: Good try. When you get the answer (which is a word) it will be much simpler.

Comment: Also I edited the title a little. Sorry. It makes your question invalid.

Comment: I mean your *answer

Answer (score 1):

Is it

> debt?

To all I'm known as a negative flaw

> Debt is bad

Negative, I'm beneficial to all.

> Negative Debt is good!

Answer (score 1):

Is it

> A false eye?

To all I’m known as a negative flaw.

> Missing an eye is usually bad, so I've heard.

Negative, I’m beneficial to all.

> True Eye helps to see all? There's also eye clinics by the name and eye drops as well. Seems a bit weak though.